# Initialize function by file contents at compile time

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Is there a way to initialize a function

```
someText :: Text
```

which value will be stored in a file available at compile time?

I thought I could use TH for that, but for now I just [found](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.10/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html)

```
embedFile :: FilePath -> Q Exp
runQ :: Quasi m => Q a -> m a
```

I can only unwrap `Q` into `IO`:

```
instance Quasi IO    
instance Quasi Q
```

I guess I need `Identity` instance of [Quasi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#t:Quasi), but there is no one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# foo.txt
barbazblub
```

```hs
module FileText where
import Language.Haskell.TH

fileText :: FilePath -> Q Exp
fileText fp = LitE . StringL <$> runIO (readFile fp)
```

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Foo where

import FileText

main = putStrLn $(fileText "foo.txt")
```

```
$ runhaskell Foo.hs 
barbazblub
```

Comment: Thanks! I like both answers, but I'll accept yours because it's more detailed.

Comment: @wowofbob thanks, but MathematicalOrchid's suggestion is better – `embedStringFile`, which I wasn't aware of, is the standard version of `fileText` and therefore preferrable.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't this just

```
someText :: Text
someText = $(embedStringFile "path/to/file")
```

Am I missing something?

(It's the TH splice itself that turns `Q Exp` into some other type at run-time. You shouldn't need any typeclass instances or anything...)